# NPM live-server: command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, npm-live-server

I install live-server globally with:

`npm install -g live-server` but for some reason it is not be found and I get the following error

`bash: live-server: command not found` after command
 `live-server`

Everything is correctly installed:

```
/Users/username/npm-global/bin/live-server ->
/Users/username/npm-global/lib/node_modules/live-server/live-server.js
live-server@0.9.2 /Users/username/npm-global/lib/node_modules/live-server
├── object-assign@4.0.1
├── colors@1.1.2
├── event-stream@3.3.2 (pause-stream@0.0.11, duplexer@0.1.1, stream-combiner@0.0.4, from@0.1.3, map-stream@0.1.0, split@0.3.3, through@2.3.8)
├── opn@4.0.0 (pinkie-promise@2.0.0)
├── send@0.13.1 (escape-html@1.0.3, destroy@1.0.4, statuses@1.2.1, etag@1.7.0, fresh@0.3.0, range-parser@1.0.3, ms@0.7.1, debug@2.2.0, depd@1.1.0, mime@1.3.4, on-finished@2.3.0, http-errors@1.3.1)
├── morgan@1.7.0 (on-headers@1.0.1, basic-auth@1.0.3, depd@1.1.0, on-finished@2.3.0, debug@2.2.0)
├── connect@3.4.1 (utils-merge@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.1, debug@2.2.0, finalhandler@0.4.1)
├── faye-websocket@0.10.0 (websocket-driver@0.6.4)
├── watchr@2.3.10 (bal-util@1.18.0)
└── serve-index@1.7.3 (parseurl@1.3.1, escape-html@1.0.3, batch@0.5.3, http-errors@1.3.1, debug@2.2.0, mime-types@2.1.10, accepts@1.2.13)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BrowserSync : Command not found after installing browser-sync](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500178/browsersync-command-not-found-after-installing-browser-sync)

Comment: What does `npm bin -g` return? What does `echo $PATH` return?

Comment: `npm bin -g` returns `/Users/davidknowles/npm-global/bin`
`(not in PATH env variable)`

Comment: Add `/Users/davidknowles/npm-global/bin` to your path, as I said in my answer. `npm` is probably installed to another directory. (See which by running `which npm`.)

Comment: `echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`

Comment: `npm bin -g` solved it for me

That let me know my path with:

`/Users/MYUSERNAMEHERE/.npm-packages/bin` (not in PATH variable)

I opened .zshrc and added this line:

`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/MYUSERNAMEHERE/.npm-packages/bin`

Refresh your .zshrc and live-reload works

I am obviously using zsh but you could apply this to bash as well

I think problems arise when people install using brew versus manually and that is why the solutions vary with regard to paths as manually and homebrew install to different directories

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the path to your npm installation to your path. Just add this line at the end of `.bash_profile`. Run it in bash first, to make sure it works before putting it in `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/npm-global/bin
```

Comment: This did the job. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me as well, Thanks

Comment: If you're using `zsh`, you can add in your `~/.zshrc`: `path+=('/Users/valydia/.npm-global/bin') export PATH`

Answer (score 14):

The main problem is that node js does not know the path of the installed modules ..

Type this command to get the path of all the global modules.

```
npm bin -g
```

It will display the path (C:\Users\gf\AppData\Roaming\npm) and also show **(not in PATH env variable)**

Copy the path and add it to the path variable of your computer (just like you do while installing other software)  for eg : In Windows 7 - Right click on my computer ->select properties -> select advanced system settings -> environment variables

[image]

Double click on the Path variable

[image]

In the variable value first type a semicolon and paste the path which you copied and that's it every thing should work now..

Comment: It worked but only as a system variable in my case. Thanks for the help! :-)

Answer (score 7):

In my case (Ubuntu with npm installed from package) `live-server` module was not installed. It helps:

```
npm install -g live-server
```

Answer (score 7):

Just a note, don't just blindly copy and paste the path /Users/username be sure you do the

```
npm bin -g
```

as explained by others and get that actual path into `export PATH=$PATH:/YourActualPathHERE`

Comment: Will I need to do this every time I reset my computer if I don't add that to my .bash_profile ?

Comment: Answering my own question, the answer is yes, yes you do unless you add to your .bash_profile or .zshrc .

Answer (score 6):

try to install as root/Administrator

```
sudo npm install -g live-server
```

Hope this will solve your problem.. its works for me...

Answer (score 1):

**If you on windows 10.**

Assuming Nodejs is installed, npm is installed, GitBash terminal is installed

1.Install  Linux subsystem for windows:
Open PowerShell and type:

**Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux**

3. Open gitBash.exe terminal and type:
   **$ npm bin -g**
4. Copy the Path:
   **C:\Users\YourMachineName\AppData\Roaming\npm**

5.Click the search icon and type Environment...

6.Choose Edit environment variables for your account

[image]

[image]

[image]

7. Go back to Your code Editor, or another terminal and test the work.
8. There is a probability that Powershell will not work. That is why you should select GitBash as your default terminal if you develop a website using VSCode on Windows.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Update to http-server. You can install globally using

```
npm install --global http-server
```

You can find the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use live-server in your project as a dev-dependency. Yes, it is not the recommended way. But it is a shortcut and will save your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

My npm live-server works well until it suddenly stopped without any error.
I then must change to use live-server of Visual Studio code instead.
After read many article i found that my path variable missing C:\Windows\System32\ variable.
Check carefully your path environment variable to make sure you have all the addresses needed.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
npm install -g http-server
    
http-server

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process

npm install -g live-server

live-server
```