# BrowserSync: command not found after installing locally

Tags: node.js, npm, browser-sync

I ran the following command for my node app:

```
$ npm install browser-sync --save-dev
```

Installation was successful, `browser-sync` appears in my `package.json` file as well as my `node_modules` directory.

However, when I run `$ browser-sync --version` to check that it's working, I get the following error:

> bash: browser-sync: command not found

Why isn't this working?

**Note**: this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500178/browsersync-command-not-found-after-installing-browser-sync) is similar, but I don't want to have to install it globally as in this question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you're trying to **use a module locally which is normally installed globally**. *Modules installed globally end up on your `PATH` environment variable*, which is why you can run them from the terminal as you're trying to do:

```
$ browser-sync --version
```

If you want to use the `browser-sync` module from a local install you will have to **prepend the full path to the `browser-sync` binary from within your `.bin` directory** since all locally installed modules are  placed within your current working directory `node_modules` directory. i.e. Node modules go in `./node_modules`, executables go in `./node_modules/.bin/`. So in order to run the `browser-sync` binary from a local install do the following:

```
./node_modules/.bin/browser-sync  --version
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you, this helped me resolve my issue. Running "./node_modules/.bin/browser-sync  --version" from the project folder was the fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed browser-sync using `npm --save` or `npm --save-dev` you can run it by writing a script in your package.json. Here's an example of a script I added:

```
{
...
"scripts": {
    "dev-server": "browser-sync start --server 'public' --files 'public'"
  },
...
}
```

You can run the scripts from you project's root directory like so

```
npm run dev-server
```

This will run whatever command is set to `dev-server` in your script. In this case it will run browser-sync for the app/site in a folder called `/public` and watch for any file changes in the `/public` folder. I know this question is a bit old but it was unanswered and hopefully I can save someone time in the future.

Comment: This worked for me! The answers for this question are really disjointed, so I'm glad this worked. The only thing to mention is that I created a folder called public and put the index.html and css folder in there. I don't know if this works without that, but otherwise it worked great.

Comment: And just to be even more specific, I only put the index.html file in the public folder, because I had another watch/build runner and it didn't like that I put the CSS folder in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers still work, but a newer approach has emerged since `npm` added the `npx` command: `npx <package-name>`.

> This command allows you to run an arbitrary command from an npm
> package (either one installed locally, or fetched remotely), in a
> similar context as running it via npm run.

Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npx

In this case, you would run `npx browser-sync`.